# ADD time 23:59:59.999 to end date for between

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have been having an issue with using the following:

```
Column_Name BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate.
```

This is because the @EndDate = 00:00:00.000 for the time, which doesn't pick up all the values for that day.

How would I convert the @EndDate (Always 00:00:00.000) to always be Date + 23:59:59.999?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One option that avoids needing to add EndDate + 23:59:59.999 is to not use the `between` comparison and instead use `column_name >= @StartDate and column_name < @EndDate +1`

Comment: +1 `EndDate + 23:59:59.999` would get rounded up to the next day anyway. It would need to be `EndDate + 23:59:59.997` to avoid that.

Comment: I still would go with `and column_name < DATEADD(Day, 1,@EndDate) to avoid implicit casting.

Comment: < @EndDate +1 should result in values matching for EndDate through EndDate + 23:59:59.999.

Comment: I read that microsoft is considering to prevent datetime + 1 in a later sql version. A true brainfart from microsoft that will never happen. If anyone can show me that the implicit casting will slow the performance i will accept Wayne's explanation, otherwise i will always pick the datetime + 1 version.

Comment: I gave it a +1, but don't do "@EndDate + 1".  Use dateadd to be explicit about what unit you're adding to the datetime.

Comment: Remember, implicit casting is a performance issue, it is a "what I wanted" issue.  If for some reason, your @enddate variable was as varchar instead of a datetime it would not work as expected.  The rule I was taught was to NEVER rely on implicit conversions.

Answer (score 19):

Please note the accuracy and rounding of the [DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) type in SQL Server 2005:

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

SQL Server 2008 introduced the [DATETIME2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) type which has an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds.  So in SQL Server 2008 you could do:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '2011-10-07 00:00:00.000'
SELECT DATEADD(MS, -1, DATEADD(D, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME2, @d)))
```

Alternatively you may want to avoid the BETWEEN operator in this case:

```
@StartDate <= Column_Name AND Column_Name < DATEADD(D, 1, @EndDate)
```

Comment: Tom wouldn't the second example be:  Column_Name >= @StartDate AND Column_Name < DATEADD(D, 1, @EndDate)

Comment: `@StartDate <= Column_Name` is the same as `Column_Name >= @StartDate`

Answer (score 8):

You can change the time in a date like this (I'm using `getdate()` as an example):

```
select cast(convert(char(8), getdate(), 112) + ' 23:59:59.99' as datetime)
```

Explanation:

`convert(char(8), getdate(), 112)` converts the date to `yyyymmdd` format (as string).

Then you can just append the desired time, and convert the whole string to `datetime` again.

---

*EDIT:*

It slows the performance when you do the casting on a **database column**, yes.
But he has a datetime **variable** and he just uses the casting to change the time in the variable once
--> I see no performance issue if he uses my code to change his `@EndDate` variable.

Valid point, however. Casting is not a good solution in all situations.

Comment: casting between datetime and varchar really slows the performance. You should try to avoid that unless it is needed. Also apply to other surgestions

Answer (score 8):

Since the advent of `datetime2` datatype, I have been struggling with this problem.  To calculate the end of day as a datetime2 datatype I add the number of seconds in a day to the =date= then subtract 100 nanoseconds.  Voila:

```
declare @bod datetime2

declare @eod datetime2 

set @bod = cast (GETDATE() as DATE) 

set @eod = DATEADD(ns, -100, DATEADD(s, 86400, @bod))

print @bod

print @eod

-- answer:

2013-12-01 00:00:00.0000000

2013-12-01 23:59:59.9999999
```

Now I'm off to `datetimeoffset` data type.

Comment: Sorry, but this assumes he's using a `datetime2` type, which I believe aren't available for SQL Server 2005 (although it's probably that he's upgraded since initially posting this question).  Beyond that, there's a number of weird things that happen with casting [date/time/timestamp types on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  This also illustrates a commonly held misconception about ranges, which is why I advocate avoiding `BETWEEN` altogether.

Comment: The datepart nanosecond is not supported by date function dateadd for data type datetime.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this:

```
select @endDate = dateadd(ms,-3,dateadd(day,1,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@endDate), 0)))
```

when @endDate is '5/3/2013'

Comment: This one made it much easier to edit my current query. Only needed to edit the one line where I made my variable, instead of going back through and getting rid of '=' everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

```
--Execution / post date is 1 Feb. 2020

-- sql server this month start and end
select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) -- 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000
select DATEADD(second,-1, datediff(day,0,EOMONTH(getdate()))+1) -- 2020-02-29 23:59:59.000

-- sql server this day start and end
select DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0) -- 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000
select DATEADD(second,-1, datediff(dd,0,getdate())+1) -- 2020-02-01 23:59:59.000

-- sql server last 30 days start and end
select DATEADD(day, -30, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())) -- 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000
select DATEADD(second,-1, datediff(dd,0,getdate())+1) -- 2020-02-01 23:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `between` if your end date is set to `00:00:00` of the next day:

`ColumnName between @StartDate and convert(datetime, convert(date, @EndDate + 1))`

This converts the next day to a `date`, which removes the hours information, then you convert it back to a `datetime` which adds default hour information: `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any variant of the date from parts functions. For example, let's use [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME2(0) = '2011-10-07 04:32:12.000';

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), MONTH(@d), DAY(@d), 23, 59, 59, 0);

-- 2011-10-07 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply strip the original column of time indication. Eg. if it's delivery notes or invoices from a date.. that has a datetime stamp, you could cast/convert it to only date. That way you lookup of >= @datefrom and <= @dateto will work.
like where cast('Datetimefield' as date) >= @datefrom and cast('Datetimefield' as date) <=  @dateto

Comment: Technically this will work, but performance over large sets will suffer due to the conversion. Adding +1 day and using less than on the argument is still a better solution. This works better if you cha get the datatype in the schema or add another column so you can index on the date only.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CAST(Start_Date AS DATE) >= '01-01-2024 00:00:00 000000'
CAST(End_Date AS DATE) <= '31-01-2024 00:00:00 000000'
```

Use the `CAST` function, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -2):

I first convert the original datetime to begin of the day, then add hours and seconds to it:

DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME

SET @start = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

SET @end = DATEADD(HOUR, 23, DATEADD(n, 59, @start))

PRINT @start

PRINT @end

Oct 27 2017 12:00AM

Oct 27 2017 11:59PM