# Retrieve dates between two given dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my current SQL query:

```
DECLARE
@FromDate datetime=NULL,
@ToDate datetime=NULL


SET @FromDate = '10/11/2014'
SET @ToDate = '11/11/2014'

SELECT *
FROM
    tblUSer
WHERE
    ((convert(VARCHAR(10), CreatedDate, 103) BETWEEN convert(VARCHAR(10), @FromDate, 103) AND convert(VARCHAR(10), @ToDate, 103))
```

But I get only two records after executing this query, i.e. for 11/11/2014, and I have four records in my table over all:

[image]

How can I get the desired records between the date range when both from and to dates are given and also when both are null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
DECLARE
@FromDate datetime=NULL,
@ToDate datetime=NULL


SET @FromDate = '10/11/2014'
SET @ToDate = '11/11/2014'

SELECT *
FROM
    tblUSer
WHERE
    CreatedDate >= @FromDate AND
    CreatedDate <=  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT statements you are using are not necessary. The following will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    tblUSer
WHERE
    CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate And @ToDate
```

Also, keep in mind that by not specifying a time, it defaults to midnight. So, the ToDate is actually '11/11/2014 00:00:00'. The results of your query should only be a single row (the first row), because the others occur after midnight on 11/11/2014.

You also stated FromDate and ToDate could be null. In this case you should set them to lower and upper boundary values, as appropriate, to return the desired results.

Comment: yeah what you are saying is right.. how can i get all three rows?

Comment: You can get all three rows by setting @ToDate = '11/14/2014'

Comment: I can't tell the user to select `14/11/2014` to get three records. I just want to know why its not working and what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```sql
DECLARE @FromDate AS datetime, @ToDate AS datetime


SET @FromDate = '12/12/2008'
SET @ToDate = '12/12/2009'

SELECT *
FROM tblUSer
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: when i tried your query and gave `SET @FromDate = '10/11/2014'
SET @ToDate = '11/11/2014'` i get only one record of date `10/11/2014`

Comment: maybe you have one record that satisfy the condition

Answer (score 0):

From [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691742/add-time-235959-999-to-end-date-for-between):

```
/* Variables*/
    DECLARE
        @FromDate datetime=NULL,
        @ToDate datetime=NULL

    SET @FromDate = '10/11/2014'
    SET @ToDate = '11/11/2014'

/* Sample Data */
    ; WITH tblUser AS 
      (
        SELECT CreatedDate 
        FROM 
          (
            VALUES
                ('2014-11-10 15:47:21.755'),
                ('2014-11-11 16:27:24.790'), 
                ('2014-11-11 18:21:10.810'), 
                ('2014-11-13 18:31:10.583')
          ) AS Value(CreatedDate))

/* Actual Query */
    SELECT *
    FROM
        tblUSer
    WHERE
        CreatedDate >= @FromDate AND
        CreatedDate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)

/* Works because:*/
    PRINT 'This ToDate value will return no records from 11/11 beyond something created exactly at midnight:'
    PRINT @ToDate

    PRINT 'This value would return all records created at any time within 11/11:'
    PRINT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to convert date to varchar in your sql query

Secondly, The records have a different format of date ('yyyy-mm-dd') and the values you are supplying has a 'dd-mm-yyyy' format which could be a problem.

That is how I use it

```
select dateColumn,* from TABLename where dateColumn between'YYYY-MM-DD' and 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

And it works for me :)

Comment: thanks for the answer @Aman... however this still gets only 1 record. and that conversion to varchar gives me date in format `dd/mm/yyyy` refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for details

Comment: @SidM as sql sevrer takes the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.  Use '121' code instead of 103 in your conversion "convert(VARCHAR(10), FromDate, 121)"

Comment: you will get your work done without the conversion, it is hence an overhead.