# Convert to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple SQL statement

```
select convert(datetime, '1/1/2018')
```

when I look at the output of it I see it is getting converted to `2018-01-01 00:00:00.000`. Is it possible in the time section it gets the end of day time rather than the beginning of day?

I am using this to fetch data based on the converted date and it fails to retrieve this record `1/1/2018 15:10:43` because of the time thing.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Update

Looks like I can do `SELECT DATEADD(ms, -3, '5/31/2018') + 1` to solve my issue..Got the idea from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691742/add-time-235959-999-to-end-date-for-between)

Comment: Add 1 day and use `<` comparator. That is, `my_col < convert(datetime,'1/2/2018')`.

Comment: This is an XY question.  Is it correct that what you really want to know is how to retrieve all records with a given DATE in a `datetime` column, regardless of the TIME portion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I look at the output of it I see it is getting converted to
>   2018-01-31 00:00:00.000

I can't reproduce your result. `select convert(datetime,'1/1/2018')` doesn't return Jan 31st. It returns Jan 1st.

> I am using this to fetch data based on the converted date and it fails
>   to retrieve this record 1/1/2018 15:10:43 because of the time thing

Since you are converting it to a `DATETIME`, it gets a time of `00:00:00` which is midnight. Thus, it fails to retrieve anything after midnight, like `15:10` on the same day. The easiest thing is to make your operator `<` the *next day...* so you don't have to account for hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds...

`where fetch < '20180102'`

Notice I didn't use `convert` since SQL Server will handle that for us, but feel free to add it if it makes it clearer for you.

`where fetch < convert(datetime,'20180102')`

Also note that I used ANSI standars of `YYYYMMDD`. Other methods, which will cause issues when you use `DATETIME2` or want a more precise measurement, is to add `seconds` to your date and use `<=`.

```
select dateadd(second,86399,convert(datetime,'20180101'))
```

Notice this has milliseconds of `000` though, so this can creep up on you later which is why I suggest using the *next day*.

For milliseconds...

```
select dateadd(millisecond,86399999,convert(datetime2,'20180101'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot scsimon..I got my issue solved with elect DATEADD(ms, -3, '5/31/2018') + 1 ..got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691742/add-time-235959-999-to-end-date-for-between

Comment: That's one way, which is far less clean but it is similar to what I explained in my answer if you read it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a converted `datetime` to compare you need to be aware that it will always receive a time of 00:00:00.000. This will cause anything on that given date but with a greater time to be excluded from your results set.

To solve this issue you need to set the time on the field you are searching on to match. The code below will make every result in your datetime field have a time of 00:00:00.000, the same as your converted date.

```
(DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, my_col)
```