# SQL : wrong total returned

Tags: sql, sum, invoice

I'm working on a SQL project where I have a stored procedure where I return the total invoices of each customer for a specific time period. I have written a stored procedure that returns the total amount for each customer however the total results are a little bit above the real amount.

- Customer 1 Total: 23 (finding him with query individually)
- Customer 1: Total 25 (using a stored procedure)

This is my stored procedure and I have the tables below. Thank you for your time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE QUERY4 
    @p_StartDate DATE, @p_EndDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ct.*, SUM(iv.Total) AS Total
    FROM Customer AS ct, Invoice AS iv
    WHERE ct.CustomerId = iv.CustomerId 
      AND iv.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @p_StartDate AND @p_EndDate
    GROUP BY ct.CustomerId, ct.FirstName, ct.LastName, ct.Company, ct.Country, ct.State, ct.City, 
            ct.Address, ct.PostalCode, ct.Phone, ct.Fax, ct.Email, ct.SupportRepId
    ORDER BY Total DESC
 END;
```

[image: Tables]

Comment: if you want total invoice of each custumer then you just group by customerid not other columns ,  because customers possibly have same name or maybe in some invoices details are not entered correctly

Comment: Post the query that you use to find the total for an individual customer.

Comment: I can't delete the rest considering that I have them included in select.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first group the invoices in a sub-query.
Then `INNER JOIN` that to the customers.

```
    SELECT ct.*, inv.Total
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT i.CustomerId, SUM(i.Total) AS Total
       FROM Invoice i
       WHERE i.InvoiceDate >= @p_StartDate
         AND i.InvoiceDate <= @p_EndDate
       GROUP BY i.CustomerId
    ) inv
    INNER JOIN Customer AS ct
      ON ct.CustomerId = inv.CustomerId 
    ORDER BY inv.Total DESC
```

But this should give the same result as you got before.
So maybe you could share the query you used that found 23.
Also, is InvoiceDate a DATE type or a DATETIME?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, the results I'm now getting are the same as when I manually add the totals.

Comment: @sotis Glad that it solved your issue.  But to me it seems that your original query should give the same result. So I'm suspecting that InvoiceDate is a datetime field.  And f.e. `'2019-12-15 00:00:01'` is not smaller or equal than the date `'2019-12-15'`. But `cast('2019-12-15 00:00:01' as date) <= cast('2019-12-15' as date)` does evaluate as true.

Comment: InvoiceDate is indeed a datetime field, you are correct.

Comment: @sotis If that's the case, perhaps you'll find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7691846/4003419) an interesting trick.  The thing is that doing something like `where cast(datetimecol1 as date) <= @datevariable` would work, but because of the CAST an index on datetimecol1 could be ignored by the query optimizer.  Thus making the query slower.  Well, that's only if it's indexed though.